# Subprocess.Popen spits output on screen even with stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Tags: python

I'm using multiple commands to run:

e.g. `cd foo/bar; ../../run_this -arg1 -arg2="yeah_ more arg1 arg2" arg3=/my/path finalarg`

Running with:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
```

But this spits output on screen `(Python 2.7.5)`
And out is empty string.

Comment: Could it be printing to stderr? You may need to redirect that to `subprocess.PIPE` as well.

Comment: Probably you have stderr, you shall add `stderr = subprocess.STDOUT` - so it will be joined to the output

Comment: aha .. that was the case!! Thanks both of you! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment I added stderr too and that worked!:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `shell=True`, so you're basically reading the standard output of the shell spawned, not the standard output of the program you want to run.

I'm guessing you're using `shell=True` to accommodate the directory changing.  Fortunately, `subprocess` can take care of that for you (by passing a directory via the `cwd` keyword argument):

```
import subprocess
import shlex
directory = 'foo/bar'
cmd = '../../run_this -arg1 -arg2="yeah_ more arg1 arg2" arg3=/my/path finalarg'
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), cwd=directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
```

Comment: How will it catch STDERR if not specified in the parameters to `Popen()`?